# Angular 7: Lazy loading WebWorkers causes ng serve to crash on first reload

Tags: angular, angular-cli, lazy-loading, web-worker

I am trying to lazy load a module containing WebWorkers in Angular 7, using worker-plugin and Comlink.
Basically, I've followed the tutorial from [here](https://medium.com/lacolaco-blog/enjoyable-webworkers-in-angular-41cfeb0e6519) and it compiles and works fine.

When running `ng serve`, it crashes on the first reload with `TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined`.

The code is on GitHub.
https://github.com/jetkiwi/angular-comlink-lazyload-example

```
PS C:\Users\jetkiwi\Documents\Development\angular-comlink-lazyload-example> ng serve
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
 29% building 163/164 modules 1 active ...example\src\app\lazy\worker\markdown.tsWarning (worker-plugin): output.globalObject is set to "window". It must be set to "self" to support HMR in Workers.

Date: 2019-03-18T10:51:05.270Z
Hash: faa40366aaa3831a6ec7
Time: 10417ms
chunk {es2015-polyfills} es2015-polyfills.js, es2015-polyfills.js.map (es2015-polyfills) 284 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {lazy-lazy-module} lazy-lazy-module.js, lazy-lazy-module.js.map (lazy-lazy-module) 21.5 kB  [rendered]
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 11 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 236 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 8.77 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 16.3 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 3.76 MB [initial] [rendered]
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
i ｢wdm｣: Compiling...

Date: 2019-03-18T10:51:11.248Z - Hash: f7b1396d7e355dec9ed5 - Time: 2026ms
6 unchanged chunks
chunk {lazy-lazy-module} lazy-lazy-module.js, lazy-lazy-module.js.map (lazy-lazy-module) 21.5 kB  [rendered]

ERROR in : TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined
    at getAssignmentTargetKind (C:\Users\jetkiwi\Documents\Development\angular-comlink-lazyload-example\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:10228:28)
    at Object.isAssignmentTarget (C:\Users\jetkiwi\Documents\Development\angular-comlink-lazyload-example\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:10271:16)
    at checkObjectLiteral (C:\Users\jetkiwi\Documents\Development\angular-comlink-lazyload-example\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:47313:45)
    at checkExpressionWorker (C:\Users\jetkiwi\Documents\Development\angular-comlink-lazyload-example\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:51812:28)
    at checkExpression (C:\Users\jetkiwi\Documents\Development\angular-comlink-lazyload-example\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:51757:42)
    at checkExpressionWithContextualType (C:\Users\jetkiwi\Documents\Development\angular-comlink-lazyload-example\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:51587:26)
    at checkApplicableSignature (C:\Users\jetkiwi\Documents\Development\angular-comlink-lazyload-example\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:48906:35)
    at chooseOverload (C:\Users\jetkiwi\Documents\Development\angular-comlink-lazyload-example\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:49225:26)
    at resolveCall (C:\Users\jetkiwi\Documents\Development\angular-comlink-lazyload-example\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:49177:26)
    at resolveCallExpression (C:\Users\jetkiwi\Documents\Development\angular-comlink-lazyload-example\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:49484:20)
    at resolveSignature (C:\Users\jetkiwi\Documents\Development\angular-comlink-lazyload-example\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:49772:28)
    at getResolvedSignature (C:\Users\jetkiwi\Documents\Development\angular-comlink-lazyload-example\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:49804:26)
    at checkCallExpression (C:\Users\jetkiwi\Documents\Development\angular-comlink-lazyload-example\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:49896:29)
    at checkExpressionWorker (C:\Users\jetkiwi\Documents\Development\angular-comlink-lazyload-example\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:51823:28)
    at checkExpression (C:\Users\jetkiwi\Documents\Development\angular-comlink-lazyload-example\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:51757:42)
    at resolveDecorator (C:\Users\jetkiwi\Documents\Development\angular-comlink-lazyload-example\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:49691:28)

i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

**Update**
My colleague has found that running with the `--aot` option prevents it from crashing.

Comment: seems to be a problem with the typescript version. What version do you have?

Comment: I'm currently on typescript@3.2.4. I've just tested with 3.1.6, 3.3.3333, 3.4.0-rc and still have the same issue.

Comment: there are a few suggestions in this link that might be useful. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28810

Comment: Similar issue being discussed here.
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/13700#discussion_r268188296

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating @angular-devkit/build-angular to 0.13.8 resolved the issue.

I'm assuming it was something related to @ngtools/webpack.
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases/tag/v7.3.8